# Access Django's class model and display on template

Tags: python, django

I am new to django and is working on my pet project. I am having a bit of problem accessing the data from one of my classes in models.py

models.py

```
class Team_Region(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    # String representation
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Team_Name(models.Model):
    t_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='team_logos', blank=True)
    region_member = models.ForeignKey(Team_Region, related_name='regions')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.t_name + ' - ' + str(self.region_member) 

class Team_Member(models.Model):
    mem_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    member_of_team = models.ForeignKey(Team_Name, related_name='teams')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.mem_name + ' - ' + self.position + ' - ' + str(self.member_of_team)
```

views.py

```
# Display regions in list
class TeamRegionListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'regions_list'
    model = Team_Region
    template_name = 'dota_teams/team_regions_list.html'

    # Display all teams associated to the region
class TeamRegionDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'region_teams'
    model = Team_Region
    template_name = 'dota_teams/team_regions_detail.html'

class MemberDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'team_members'
    model = Team_Name
    template_name = 'dota_teams/member_detail.html'
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^$', views.TeamRegionListView.as_view(), name='all_regions'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.TeamRegionDetailView.as_view(),   name='region_teams'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/(\d+)/$', views.MemberDetailView.as_view(), name='member_details'),
```

## UPDATE

team_regions_list.html

```
{% block body_block %}

<div class="row">
    {% for region in regions_list %}
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4">
            <a href="{{ region.id }}" class="thumbnail" style="width: 350px; height:350px">
                <h4 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 150px"> {{ region.name }} </h4>
            </a>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

{% endblock %}

team_regions_detail.html

```
{% block body_block %}

<div class="row">
    {% for team in region_teams.regions.all %}
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4">
            <a href="{{ team.id }}" class="thumbnail">
                <img style="width: 100px; height:90px" src="{{ team.logo.url }}" alt="Image not found.">


                <div class="caption">
                    <h4 style="text-align:center">{{ team.t_name }}</h4>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

{% endblock %}

I'm not sure how to access the mem_name and position variables under the Team_Member class. In my views.py, if I use the model Team_Name, the ID is not properly assigned to the region and team. I have tried accessing the Team_Member by using a For loop from Team_Region and use the 'related_name' of Team_Name then access the 'related_name' of Team_Member but it won't work either (e.g. {% for member in regions_list.regions.teams.all %} ). I'm a bit loss on this.

Any suggestions please?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your models, it has the relationship:

```
Team_Region --> has many Team_Name
Team_Name  --> has many Team_Member
```

you have already defined the foreign keys with `related_name`, if you access the `Team_Member` from `Team_Region`, you have to for loop the `regions_list` first, then use the related_name `regions` to get the team names, after that for loop all the teams, use the related_name `teams` to get the team members. In your template `team_regions_list.html`, like this:

```
{%for rl in regions_list%}
    {%for tn in rl.regions.all %}
        {{tn.teams.all}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Update:**

in your views.py, the `modal` is not correct for class `TeamRegionDetailView` and `MemberDetailView`, change to：

```
# Display regions in list
class TeamRegionListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'regions_list'
    model = Team_Region
    template_name = 'dota_teams/team_regions_list.html'

    # Display all teams associated to the region
class TeamRegionDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'region_teams'
    model = Team_Name
    template_name = 'dota_teams/team_regions_detail.html'

class MemberDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'team_members'
    model = Team_Member
    template_name = 'dota_teams/member_detail.html'
```

Use `region_teams.teams.all` instead of `region_teams.regions.all`, change your `team_regions_detail.html` to :

```
<div class="row">
    {% for team in region_teams.teams.all %}
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4">
            <a href="{{ team.id }}" class="thumbnail">
                <img style="width: 100px; height:90px" src="{{ region_teams.logo.url }}" alt="Image not found.">


                <div class="caption">
                    <h4 style="text-align:center">{{ team.t_name }}</h4>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**Update 2:**
I believe that you manage your upload files incorrectly, refer to [official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/files/#using-files-in-models):

> By default, Django stores files locally, using the MEDIA_ROOT and
>   MEDIA_URL settings.

in your project `settings.py` file, add them:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and in your project `urls.py` file, add:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

After that the template can access your uploaded images with (`/media/team_logos/test.png`), eg:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/team_logos/test.png
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the input. This is what I have in my team_regions_list.html

<div class="row">
  {% for region in regions_list %}
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4">
    <a href="{{ region.id }}" class="thumbnail" style="width: 350px; height:350px">
     <h4 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 150px"> {{ region.name }} </h4>
    </a>
   </div>
  {% endfor %}
 </div>

That will display the regions. This will allow me to access the teams per region via region.id on the anchor tag.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it later when I get home. By the way, I have three templates, the team_regions_list.html displays the name of regions. When user clicks the thumbnail for a specific region, it will direct the user to team_regions_detail.html which contains the Teams assigned to that region. When the user clicks again the team logo, it will direct him/her to member_detail.html which will show the team's roster. This is what I want to achieve.

Comment: @tangoward i used your `team_regions_list.html`, it will lead to `team_regions_detail.html`.

Comment: I changed my codes to the ones you mentioned but the team logos won't display anymore.

Comment: the team logo is in Team_Name, change from `team.logo.url` to `region_teams.logo.url`

Comment: Logos wont still load

Comment: i believe that you have incorrect settings for your project, check the update.

Comment: I already have it in my settings.py, the MEDIA_ROOT and URL and have STATIC and SETTINGS imported in my project's urls.py. Still the logos won't load.

Comment: can you inspect the browser to check what's the url for the logo?

Comment: When I changed my files to the codes you suggested, the region list wont load therefore I can't click any link that will direct me to the logos page.

Comment: The way i did it before was to loop in {% for region in regions_list %} so i can access the "name" of region (e.g. region.name )

Comment: Hi Tiny.D, thanks for the idea. I got it working by nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to thank Tiny.D for the idea on the solution.

I updated my views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
```

from .models import Team_Region, Team_Name, Team_Member

```
#Display regions in list
class TeamRegionListView(ListView):
context_object_name = 'regionlist'
model = Team_Region
template_name = 'dota_teams/team_region_list.html'



#Display teams associated to the region
class TeamRegionDetailView(DetailView):
context_object_name = 'regiondetail'
model = Team_Region
template_name = 'dota_teams/team_region_detail.html'


#Display members of each team
class TeamDetailView(DetailView):
context_object_name = 'teamdetail'
model = Team_Region
template_name = 'dota_teams/team_detail.html'
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^$', views.TeamRegionListView.as_view(), name='region_list'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.TeamRegionDetailView.as_view(), name='region_detail'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/(\d+)/$', views.TeamDetailView.as_view(), name='member'),
```

The logic of the team_region_list.html and team_region_detail.html are the same to my post above.

team_detail.html

```
{% block body_block %}

<div class="row">
    {% for member in teamdetail.regions.all %}
        {% for member_detail in member.teams.all %}
            <h4>{{ member_detail.mem_name }}</h4>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

For the team_detail.html, I just need to perform a nested loop just what Tiny.D mentioned. Everything is working now. Thanks.